# How to disable vibration for the back and search buttons?

Tags: buttons

How can I disable the vibration for the back and search buttons?

Comment: You had two unrelated questions here, so I have split it up. Please ask another question relating to the clock. You can see your original question here: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/posts/1044/revisions

Answer (score 3):

You cannot disable the vibration of those two buttons via a setting on the phone. If you have a rooted phone you can disable vibration for all three buttons via a [registry setting](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=23450328&postcount=5)

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\OEM\KeyState]
>   "application_btn_vibrate3"=dword:1